# Paypal onApproved method, won't run my save to Firebase function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, paypal

When I try to save the subscriptionID to Firebase DB inside the onApproved method for PayPal payment integration API, I get this random error regarding the firebase code, but if I run my Firebase code on the created or mounted does run well.

The payment goes through and I get the subscriptionID I will share below the visual details and code.

What I want is to save the subscriptionID on my DB so I can pull and show it on their profile, I want to also save a state on the store depending on the title of the sub like if they are basic pro or premium subscribers.

So I created an object on vuex store as, I know it may sound complex but I want to assign these values to the current user. I am using Vue.

Store:

```
state: {
    authenticated: false,
    user: {
      loggedIn: false,
      data: null
    },
    subscriber: {
      basic: false,
      pro: false,
      premium: false,
    }
  }, ...
```

onApproved code: "I get the subscriberID back from the PayPal call but I want to save it in firebase but Firebase code will drop ref error even though it worked on mounted or created"

```
onApprove: async function(data, actions) {

            /**
             * NOTE
             * - Save the subscription id in your Database
             * - This is important to ensure you can always
             * - Check on the status when user logs in or wants
             * - to make payment
             */


             console.log(data)


            // 4. Remove the selected package from the local storage

            // 5. Let's use swal to give us an alert once transaction is completed
              Swal.fire({
                icon: "success",
                title: "Congratulations",
                text: "Your payment has successfully been proccessed!" + " " + "Subscription ID:" + " " + data.subscriptionID,
                confirmButtonText: "Complete",
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: () => {
                  // redirect user to dashboard or login
                  location.assign("http://localhost:1111/profile");
                },
                allowOutsideClick: false
              });

              //Firebase config this code doesn't run here but it runs on created or mounted just fine... 
                 messagesRef.child(this.userID).update(this.newSub);
                  this.newSub.packageselect = '' ;
                  this.newSub.subscrptionId = '';

            }
```

Result:

[image]

Console result:

[image]

My repo is public you are welcome to collaborate on GitHub: https://github.com/Abraham-Felix/mexdev

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is not for advertising for project collaborators - it is for asking (and answering) questions that may be useful for a broad audience.

Comment: what is advertising? i am not selling anything

Comment: Sure. Nevertheless, Stack Overflow is not for the purposes of seeking project collaborators. Posts (and their answers) are to help a broad audience besides the question author.

Comment: Ah ok it wasn’t my intention to bug, it’s hard to see same as everyone else you know we are all unique. So I never read community rules I just go straight for the objective.

Answer (score 1):

The context of `this` is different when that function (onApprove) is run, so the properties on it that you are referencing are undefined and Firebase cannot do anything with undefined values, as the error log shows.

So: outside onApprove, save a variable reference to the "this" object you want to use, and and have your onApprove function reference it by that name.

(alternatively, you could probably use `bind` if it were needed)